# Heat equation in non-dimensional form behaving differently than in usual format

Tags: finite-element, time-integration, heat-transfer

Starting from
$$
c_p \frac{\partial u }{\partial t} = k \nabla^2 u
$$
in a one dimensional domain [0,1] where $c_p$ and $k$ are modeling two different materials:
$$
k =
\begin{cases}
1 ~\text{if} ~x < 0.5\\
2.0 ~\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
$$
c_p =
\begin{cases}
10^{-8} ~\text{if} ~x < 0.5\\
1.0 ~\text{else}
\end{cases}
$$

I decided to refactor $c_p$ to the right hand side such that
$$
\frac{\partial u }{\partial t} = \frac{k} {c_p}\nabla^2 u
$$
I solve both approaches using finite elements with Lagrange interpolation and Crank-Nicolson.
However, both solutions are different (this is a random time step, the trend is similar for all time steps):
[image]

The one with $c_p$ refactored shows a flat solution for $x<0.5$, whereas the original equation has a linear solution. This difference disappears when the material properties are homogeneous, which makes me think I might be committing some mistake in my finite element formulation. The code to run both examples is:

```py
from fenics import *

cp_electrolyte = 1e-8
k_electrolyte = 1.0
k_electrode = 2.0
cp_electrode = 1.0
scan_rate = 1.0
output_dir = "./"

mesh = UnitIntervalMesh(100)

V = FunctionSpace(mesh, "CG", 1)
u, v = TrialFunction(V), TestFunction(V)

Vlimit = 1.0
tlimit = Vlimit / abs(scan_rate)


class Materials(UserExpression):
    def __init__(self, electrode, electrolyte, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # This part is new!
        self.electrolyte = electrolyte
        self.electrode = electrode

    def eval(self, values, x):
        if x[0] < 0.5:
            values[0] = self.electrolyte
        else:
            values[0] = self.electrode


k = Materials(k_electrode, k_electrolyte)
cp = Materials(cp_electrode, cp_electrolyte)

normal = False


def forward():

    dt_value = 1e-2
    dt = Constant(dt_value)
    u_n = Function(V)
    if normal:
        a = cp * u / dt * v * dx + k * \
            inner(Constant(1.0 / 2.0) * grad(u), grad(v)) * dx
        L = (
            cp * u_n / dt * v * dx
            - k * inner(Constant(1.0 / 2.0) * grad(u_n), grad(v)) * dx
        )
    else:
        a = u / dt * v * dx + k / cp * \
            inner(Constant(1.0 / 2.0) * grad(u), grad(v)) * dx
        L = (
            u_n / dt * v * dx
            - k / cp * inner(Constant(1.0 / 2.0) * grad(u_n), grad(v)) * dx
        )

    t = 0
    T = tlimit * 5
    n_steps = int(T / dt_value)

    bcval = Expression("t", t=t, degree=1)

    def Left(x, on_boundary):
        return x[0] < DOLFIN_EPS and on_boundary
    bc = DirichletBC(V, bcval, Left)

    u_sol = Function(V)
    if normal:
        output = "potential.pvd"
    else:
        output = "potential_ratio.pvd"
    potential_pvd = File(output)
    while t < T:
        solve(a == L, u_sol, bcs=bc)
        t += dt_value
        bcval.t = t
        potential_pvd << u_sol
        u_n.assign(u_sol)

    return u_n


u_n = forward()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applied division is fine, what went wrong here, is the application of Stoke's theorem. If you multiply with the test function you get following term:

$$\int \frac{1}{c_p}\nabla\left(-k\nabla u\right) v d\Omega$$
But
$$\int \frac{1}{c_p}\nabla\left(-k\nabla u\right) v d\Omega \neq \int \frac{1}{c_p} \left(k\nabla u\right) \cdot \left(\nabla v\right) d\Omega+\int \frac{1}{c_p} (-k \nabla u) v d\partial\Omega$$
You miss the derivative of $\frac{1}{c_p}$, exactly:
$$-\int \left(\nabla \frac{1}{c_p}\right) \cdot \left(-k\nabla u\right) v d\Omega$$

If you add this term in the second formulation, the results should be identical.

One more thing, the heat flux $q=-k\nabla u$, so if $k$ is dependent on $x$, you should not move it outside of the divergence operator. Also for completeness you miss $\rho$ in front of the time derivative as well.

*Edit*

While I agree that integrating $c_p$ inside the mass matrix is much, much simpler, the reason why the second variant fails, is the missing derivative of the function $\frac{1}{c_p}$. This missing description of the change in value in $c_p$ is present if used in the mass matrix.

So how can you incorporate this?

$c_p$ can be written as $c_p=a + H(x-x_0) (b-a)$ with $H(\cdot)$ the [Heavyside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) which has as derivative $\delta(x)$ the Dirac delta function. $a, b$ and $x_0$ the corresponding values.

Now, the contribution $\nabla(\frac{1}{c_p})=\frac{-1}{c_p^2} (b-a) \delta(x-x_0)$ is
$$-\int \left(\frac{-1}{c_p^2} (b-a) \delta(x-x_0)\right) \cdot \left(-k\nabla u\right) v d\Omega \neq 0$$.

The simplest way to incorporate such a contribution in finite element methods is to use a [mollified version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) of the distribution.
I am not an expert on fenics, but [here is an example of this](https://fenicsproject.org/qa/7941/applying-dirac-function-using-fenics-pointsource-function/). It is likely a good idea to use a mollifier  on the Heavyside step function and calculate its derivative to make it consistent.

*Second Edit*

The following code demonstrates that the error is indeed in the application of Stoke's theorem.

```
import fenics
import gmsh
import numpy
from fenics import (DOLFIN_EPS, Constant, DirichletBC, Expression, File,
                    Function, FunctionSpace, TestFunction, TrialFunction,
                    UnitIntervalMesh, UserExpression, atan, dx, grad, inner,
                    interpolate, nabla_grad, pi, project, solve)

cp_electrolyte = 1e-8
k_electrolyte = 1.0
k_electrode = 2.0
cp_electrode = 1.0
scan_rate = 1.0
output_dir = "./"
eps=1e-4

mesh = UnitIntervalMesh(1000)

V = FunctionSpace(mesh, "CG", 1)
Q = FunctionSpace(mesh, "DG", 0)  # this space for the derivative of cp
u, v = TrialFunction(V), TestFunction(V)

Vlimit = 1.0
tlimit = Vlimit / abs(scan_rate)


def heavyside(x, eps):
    value = 1 / 2 + 1 / pi * atan(x / eps)
    return value


class Materials(UserExpression):
    def __init__(self, electrode, electrolyte, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # This part is new!
        self.electrolyte = electrolyte
        self.electrode = electrode

    def eval(self, values, x):
        if x[0] < 0.5:
            values[0] = self.electrolyte
        else:
            values[0] = self.electrode


class MaterialsEps(UserExpression):
    def __init__(self, electrode, electrolyte, eps, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.electrolyte = electrolyte
        self.electrode = electrode
        self.eps = eps

    def eval(self, values, x):
        values[0] = self.electrolyte + \
            heavyside(x[0]-0.5, self.eps)*(self.electrode-self.electrolyte)


k = Materials(k_electrode, k_electrolyte)

# show material functions
cp = project(Materials(cp_electrode, cp_electrolyte), V)
mat = File("material.pvd")
cp.rename("projected material function", "")
mat << cp

# mollified material function
cp = project(MaterialsEps(cp_electrode, cp_electrolyte, eps), V)
dcpdx = project(cp.dx(0), Q)

mat = File("materialeps.pvd")
cp.rename("projected mollified material function", "")
mat << cp

mat = File("gradmaterialeps.pvd")
dcpdx.rename("projected derivative of mollified material function", "")
mat << dcpdx


def forward(eps):
    dt_value = 1e-2
    dt = Constant(dt_value)
    u_n = Function(V)
    heatflux = -1 * k * grad(u)
    heatflux_n = -1 * k * grad(u_n)

    if normal:
        cp = Materials(
            cp_electrode,
            cp_electrolyte)  # original discontinous material function
        a = cp * u / dt * v * dx - 1 / 2 * (inner(heatflux, grad(v)) * dx)
        L = cp * u_n / dt * v * dx + 1 / 2 * (inner(heatflux_n, grad(v)) * dx)
    else:
        # mollified material function
        cp = project(MaterialsEps(cp_electrode, cp_electrolyte, eps), V)
        dcpdx = project(cp.dx(0), Q)
        a = u * v * dx - 1 / 2 * dt * (
            inner(heatflux, grad(v)) / cp * dx + 1 /
            (cp * cp) * dcpdx * k * nabla_grad(u)[0] * v * dx)
        # with missing derivative term
        # likely, there is a better solution than explicitely access the first element of nabla_grad
        L = u_n * v * dx + 1 / 2 * dt * (
            inner(heatflux_n, grad(v)) / cp * dx + 1 /
            (cp * cp) * dcpdx * k * nabla_grad(u_n)[0] * v * dx)

    t = 0
    T = tlimit * 5
    n_steps = int(T / dt_value)

    bcval = Expression("t", t=t, degree=1)

    def Left(x, on_boundary):
        return x[0] < DOLFIN_EPS and on_boundary

    bc = DirichletBC(V, bcval, Left)

    u_sol = Function(V)
    if normal:
        output = "potential.pvd"
        u_sol.rename("u_original", "")
    else:
        output = "potential_ratio.pvd"
        u_sol.rename("u_with_mollified_term", "")
    potential_pvd = File(output)
    while t < T:
        solve(a == L, u_sol, bcs=bc)
        t += dt_value
        bcval.t = t
        potential_pvd << u_sol
        u_n.assign(u_sol)

    return u_n


for cc in [True, False]:
    normal = cc
    u_n = forward(eps)
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: $c_p$ is a function of $x$ and is discontinuous. How do you propose to do integration by parts in this case ? Formally you get a volume term like $\int k \nabla u \cdot \nabla (v/c_p) dx $. How do you propose to compute derivatives involving $c_p$ ?

Comment: @cfdlab see edit.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if the integral with the dirac delta could be represented with a line integral (point integral in the 1D case). Although I do not know what value of $1 / c_p^2$ at that point one should take.

Comment: @balborian does my posted code answers your question or are you wondering how to do this with a direct manipulation of the matrix?

Comment: It does answer my question, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it rather than using the approximation of the dirac delta.

Comment: Well, in terms of "cleaness", the best choice is obviously not to divide by $cp$. The second best choice is to manipulate the matrix directly as it is done by e.g. PointSource, though I don't know how to apply this here. I guess this would be a question for the fenics mailing list. The third option is the one above.

Comment: @balborian One more comment. In terms of cleaness, the best approach as I said is not to divide by $c_p$. But you can of course divide by a constant $\hat{c}_p$ as cfdlab suggests and keep the ratio $\frac{c_p}{\hat{c}_p}$ in front of the mass matrix. $\frac{c_p}{\hat{c}_p}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{-1}{\hat{c}_p}\nabla \left(-k\nabla u\right)$

Answer (score 0):

If $k$ depends on the spatial variables, the heat equation is of the form
$$
c_p u_t = \nabla \cdot (k \nabla u)
$$
In your case, $c_p$ also depends on space and is discontinuous. You should not try to divide by $c_p$ in this case. At best you can divide by some constant $c_{p,ref}$, e.g.
$$
c_{p,ref} = \max_{x,y} c_p(x,y)
$$
which is just one in your case. You have to integrate $c_p$ inside the mass matrix. The semi-discrete scheme would look like this
$$
M du/dt = A u
$$
$$
M_{ij} = \int c_p \phi_i \phi_j dx, \qquad A_{ij} = -\int k \nabla\phi_i \cdot \nabla \phi_j dx
$$
together with some boundary conditions. You can put in a time discretization after this.